# webpack command not recognized

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have the below commands configured in npm scripts.Now, if i run the command "npm run dev" there is no response in command prompt. However, if the run the below command as "webpack -wd" in command prompt, then the command is working as expected. why, i am not able to run this command from npm scripts. I am using windows and have set the node path in environment variables as below

```
 "scripts": {
   "dev": "webpack -wd",
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }

C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run webpack via the command line, you either need to install webpack-cli globally with `npm i -g webpack-cli` or you need to use [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) like `npx webpack -wd`. This will run webpack the same way npm scripts do.

The problem you are trying to circumvent is that webpack by default does not build the first time in watch mode, so you either need to change a file after starting webpack or run webpack without watch.

> Note: npx is part of the NPM/Node.js bundle

Comment: hi, thanks for the tip about npx.right now, running npx webpck -wd in command prompt is working as intended. However, i m trying to add this command to the scripts section of package.json and run using npm run dev. but, it is failing.